# SymPy: automatic construction of equations

Tags: python, sympy, nonlinear-functions

I found elsewhere that `x = sp.symbols('x1:{}'.format(n))`
creates a collection of `n` variables, bound to a variable `x`.
Now, I would like to use https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solveset.html#sympy.solvers.solveset.nonlinsolve
to solve a system of non-linear equations. I can construct a string containing
the expression for each row in my system of equations,
e.g. something like `x1**2+4*x2**3` etc.
How do I make `sympy` convert these into its own equations?
In the examples given in the documentation, we write
something like `[x1**2+4*x2**3,2*x1+3*x3]` and pass it to `solve()`,
but how to construct these expressions (and what is their type?)
automatically, short of hard-coding them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expressions above are sums of products of symbols, in sympy instances of `Add`

From the [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/guide.html):

> All symbolic things are implemented using subclasses of the Basic
>   class. First, you need to create symbols using Symbol("x") or numbers
>   using Integer(5) or Float(34.3). Then you construct the expression
>   using any class from SymPy. For example Add(Symbol("a"), Symbol("b"))
>   gives an instance of the Add class. You can call all methods, which
>   the particular class supports.

In your example you need to declare `x1`, `x2`, `x3` as symbols:

```
x1, x2, x3 = symbols('x1 x2 x3')
```

Once the symbols are defined, sympy converts strings automatically to its own expressions for computing. To check the type of sympy expressions use `sympify`

```
a = Symbol("a")
b = Symbol("b")
c = 'a**2 + b'
print c
(a + b)**2
type(c)
# string

from sympy import sympify
sympify(c)
type(sympify(c))
# <′...′>
```